# Sequelize unique composites fails

Tags: sequelize.js

I have the following tables:

```
class Occurrence extends Model {}
Occurrence.init({
  date: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW,
    unique: 'uniqueOccurrence'
  }
}, {
  sequelize,
  modelName: 'Occurrence'
});

class Event extends Model {}
Event.init({
  title: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
}, {
  sequelize,
  modelName: 'Event'
});
```

With the following association:

```
Event.hasMany(Occurrence, { onDelete: 'CASCADE', foreignKey: { unique: 'uniqueOccurrence' } });
Occurrence.belongsTo(Event);
```

I am trying to have a composite unique constraint that would basically only fail when both `occurrence.date` and `Event.id` together are not unique.

### Update

The composite suppose to be on ``occurrence.EventId`not`event.id`

However this for some reason fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to create an unique index with two fields and one of them is a foreign key you should define it explicitly to be able to indicate the same unique index name as indicated in the `date` field:

```js
EventId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: 'uniqueOccurrence'
},
date: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW,
    unique: 'uniqueOccurrence'
}
```

and correct an association as well:

```
Event.hasMany(Occurrence, { onDelete: 'CASCADE', foreignKey: 'EventId' });
Occurrence.belongsTo(Event, { foreignKey: 'EventId' });
```

If you wish to use two fields as a foreign key then Sequelize cannot do this (and the `foreignKey` option does not have the `unique` prop).

Comment: Anatoly i mean, `occurrence.EventId` field. not `event.id`

Comment: Ok, answer has been changed as well

Comment: Anatoly this works. Is there a way to customize the error message ? I've tried `unique: {
      args: 'uniqueOccurrence',
      msg: 'You cannot add the same date'
    }`

Comment: I didn't ry those `unique` options. Didn't work at all?

Comment: Nope didnt, they canceled the constraint altogether.

Comment: Weird, because in TypeScript this option either string or object with `name` and `msg`